# jqPlot - Overlapping of colors when plotting area chart along with bar/line plots

Tags: jqplot, area-chart

I have a use case where i want to plot area charts along with bar/line charts. I am able to do that with no issues.

The problem I am now facing is the overlapping of colors when say, bar and area are plotted together. (Sample is below). In this, as you can see, the colors of the bar are getting overcast due to the area plotted.

[Area + Bar + Line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VVHET.png)

What I would like to do is plot the area canvas as background and others as foreground. (PS: I tried by changing the sequence of plotting the series, which changes the sequence of canvas also, but the effect remains the same)

Is there a way to do that ?